# How to use database triggers in a real world project?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, triggers

I've learned a lot about triggers and active databases in the last weaks, but I've some questions about real world examples for these.

At work we use the Entity Framework with ASP.Net and an MSSQL Server. We just use the auto generated constrains and no triggers.

When I heared about triggers I asked myself the following questions:

1. Which tasks can be performed by triggers?
   e.g.: Generation of reporting data: currently the data for the reports is created in vb, but I think a trigger could handle this as well. The creation in vb takes a lot of time and the user should not need to wait for it, because it's not necessary for his work.
   Is this an example for a perfect task for a trigger?
2. How does OR-Mapper handle trigger manipulated data?
   e.g.: Do OR-Mapper recognize if a trigger manipulated data? The entity framework seems to cache a lot of data, so I'm not sure if it reads the updated data if a trigger manipulates the data, after the insert/update/delete from the framework is processed.
3. How much constraint handling should be within the database?
   e.g.: Sometimes constrains in the database seem much easier and faster than in the layer above (vb.net,...), but how to throw exceptions to the upper layer that could be handled by the OR-Mapper?
   Is there a good solution for handeling SQL exceptions (from triggers) in any OR-Mapper?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you hear about a new tool or feture it doesn't mean you have to use it everywhere. You should think about design of your application.

Triggers are used a lot when the logic is in the database but if you build ORM layer on top of your database you want logic in the business layer using your ORM. It doesn't mean you should not use triggers. It means you should use them with ORM in the same way as stored procedures or database functions - only when it makes sense or when it improves performance. If you pass a lot of logic to database you can throw away ORM and perhaps whole your business layer and use two layered architecture where UI will talk directly to database which will do everything you need - such architecture is considered "old".

1. When using ORM trigger can be helpful for some DB generated data like audit columns or custom sequences of primary key values.
2. Current ORM mostly don't like triggers - they can only react to changes to currently processed record so for example if you save Order record and your update trigger will modify all ordered items there is no automatic way to let ORM know about that - you must reload data manually. In EF all data modified or generated in the database must be set with `StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity` or `StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed` - EF fully follows pattern where logic is either in the database or in the application. Once you define that value is assigned in the database you cannot change it in the application (it will not persist).
3. Your application logic should be responsible for data validation and call persistence only if validation passes. You should avoid unnecessary transactions and roundtrips to database when you can know upfront that transaction will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I use triggers for two main purposes: auditing and updating modification/insertion times.  When auditing, the triggers push data to related audit tables.  This doesn't affect the ORM in any way as those tables are not typically mapped in the main data context (there's a separate auditing data context used when needed to look at audit data).

When recording/modifying insert/modification times, I typically mark those properties in the model as `[DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGenerationOptions.Computed )]`  This prevents any values set on in the datalayer from being persisted back to the DB and allows the trigger to enforce setting the DateTime fields properly.

It's not a hard and fast rule that I manage auditing and these dates in this way.  Sometimes I need more auditing information than is available in the database itself and handle auditing in the data layer instead.  Sometimes I want to force the application to update dates/times (since they may need to be the same over several rows/tables updated at the same time).  In those cases I might make the field nullable, but `[Required]` in the model to force a date/time to be set before the model can be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

The old Infomodeler/Visiomodeler ORM (not what you think - it was Object Role Modeling) provided an alternative when generating the physical model. It would provide all the referential integrity with triggers. For two reasons:

1. Some dbmses (notably Sybase/SQL Server) didn't have declarative RI yet, and
2. It could provide much more finely grained integrity - e.g. "no more than two children" or "sons or daughters but not both" or "mandatory son or daughter but not both".

So trigger logic related to the model in the same way that any RI constraint does. In SQL Server it handled violations with RAISERROR.

An conceptual issue with triggers is that they are essentially context-free - they always fire regardless of context (at least without great pain, and you might better include their logic with the rest of the context-specific logic.) So global domain constraints are the only place I find them useful - which I guess is another general way to identify "referential integrity".

Comment: And since when did SQL Server/Sybase not have DRI last? Early 90's?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are used to maintain **integrity** and **consistency** of data (by using **constraints**), help the database designer ensure certain actions are completed and create database **change logs**.

For example, given numeric input, if you want the value to be constrained to say, less then 100, you could write a trigger that fires for every row on update or insert, and raise an application error if the value of that column does not meet that contraint.

Suppose you want to **log historical changes** to a table. You could create a Trigger that fires **AFTER** each **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, and **DELETE**, which also inserts the data into a logging table. If you need to execute custom custom logic, then Triggers may appeal to you.